# Initialize a string with ""

Tags: c

I have this code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        size_t i;
        char arr[5] = "";
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%c ", arr[i]);

        puts("");

        memset(arr, '0', 5);
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%c ", arr[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

Why the first printf prints only spaces while the second prints zeros

Why is this happening?

Comment: What are you expecting the first one to print? What about the second?  (genuine question, and it may help others in phrasing their answers)

Comment: You are putting the char '0' instead off a null byte into memory. Just replace ``'0'`` with ``0``.

Comment: Why would you do this? Your arr[5] contains only "" and '\0' and you are trying to print up to five indices. what are you expecting from this?

Answer (score -1):

If you initialize an array with a string literal that is smaller than the array, the string, including the trailing NUL, will be copied into the array.  Any excess elements will then be initialized according to the same rules used to initialize variables with static storage duration, which for `char` is `0`. (q.v. C99 6.7.8/21)

The first printf loop is printing the array one character at a time using `%c`.
So when you initialize at the array to `""` (which is equivalent to `{'\0'}`), the array will be initialized with all zeros: the first zero from the null terminator, and the others because that's the default value for a `char` with static duration. Since a decimal value of zero represents an ASCII value of NUL, printf prints...NUL, which often shows up as a blank space.

For the second one, you're setting the array to ASCII 0, because you're setting all of the values to `0`, which is hexadecimal value 0x30 (I forget the decimal conversion). So, since you're printing `%c`, it will print ASCII 0.

Now, if you change your first printf to print a `%d`, instead of `%c`, then it will print the integer value stored in the array, which will be all zeroes. If you change the second printf to print `%x`, then it'll print a bunch of 0x30's.

Read up on the differences between `%c`, `%d`, `%x`, and the other printf flags, and how they all behave.

Comment: One simple question, why is this array "*dynamically allocated*"? Also, `""` is not `NULL`, it is equivalent to `{'\0'}` where `'\0'` is `null` but not `NULL`. And `0x30` -> `3 * 16 == 48`!!!!!

Comment: Mostly correct, but that should be NUL or `'\0'`, not NULL.  NUL and `'\0'` represent an ASCII 0 (not to be confused with an ASCII `'0'`, of course, since *that's* 48).  NULL is specifically the null *pointer* constant, which is also 0 (or `(void*)0`), but in the case of the null pointer constant, once it's converted to a pointer type, it doesn't necessarily correspond to address 0, but merely to *some* address that doesn't compare equal to any non-null pointer.  All of which requires one to be a lot more pedantic than null-terminated strings do, so it's best to keep the concepts distinct.

Comment: @Ray It turns out that it's `null` and it WAS `NUL`. I thought of it as you do. I knew I usually see `NUL` in most ascii tables, but it's `null` according to the [tag:c] standard.

Comment: @iharaob True, `null`, `NUL`, or `'\0'` would all be acceptable.  It's only `NULL` that refers specifically to the null-pointer constant.  I suppose we should be grateful that they at least differ in capitalization; for `static`, we have to rely on context to tell the various meanings apart.

Comment: Those arrays are not dynamically allocated, at least in the sense in which that phrase is typically used. They have *automatic storage duration* (which typically means they're allocated on the stack). Dynamic allocation usually refers to `malloc()` and friends, which typically allocate memory on the heap.